# Copying the address of a vector element which has to be deleted afterwards

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl-2

So I am trying to make a game in c++ with SDL2 and ran into a little problem. In order to pick up a weapon from the ground, after I check if the player is next to the object and has clicked 'E' to pick it up in an inline function from a different namespace, I have to copy its address in a variable saved in the main class and delete the object from the ground so you can't re-pick it up. It seems that after I delete the object, the pointer from the main class gets the value from another object, not that I erased.

This is the **main class .h file**:

```
class GameScene : public Scene{
public:
    GameScene();
    void init(SDL_Renderer* &renderer, int sceneIdx); //initialize variables
    void update(int &sceneIdx, double deltaTime, Vector2f screenSize); //update frame-by-frame
    void graphics(SDL_Renderer* &renderer); //render objects
    void clear(); //only called on exit
private:
    std::vector<SDL_Texture*> textures = {}; //all the textures present in the game
    std::vector<bool> movements{false, false, false, false}; //main character movements
    std::vector<Weapon> droppedWeapons = {}; //dropped pickable weapons on the ground
    std::vector<Weapon*> weapons = {nullptr, nullptr}; //slots for the primary and secondary weapon
    std::vector<Bullet> bullets = {}; //ssaves all the fired bullets on the map until deletion
    std::unordered_map<int, SDL_Rect> positionsAtlas = {}; //offsets in textures and render scales
    Cube* cube = nullptr; //main character
    int mode = 0; //0=nothing, 1=weapon --unused yet
    bool currentWeapon = 0; //saves what weapon is being used(primary or secondary)
    int mouseX, mouseY; //mouse position on screen
};
```

Here is the function call in the **.cpp file**:

```
WeaponActions::pickUpWeapons(cube, droppedWeapons, weapons, pickUp/*is E pressed*/, currentWeapon);
```

And the function in the **WeaponActions namespace**:

```
inline void pickUpWeapons(Cube* cube, std::vector<Weapon> &droppedWeapons, std::vector<Weapon*> &weapons, bool pickUp, bool &currentWeapon)
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<droppedWeapons.size();i++)
        {
            bool type = droppedWeapons[i].getType(); //type of weapon(primary or secondary)
            if(weapons[type]==nullptr && pickUp) //there is empty space in inventory
            {
                if(Math::checkCollision(cube->getPos(), cube->getScale(), droppedWeapons[i].getPos(), droppedWeapons[i].getScale())) //check if cube is near weapon
                {
                    weapons[type] = &droppedWeapons.at(i); //save address
                    droppedWeapons.erase(droppedWeapons.begin()+i); //delete element
                    currentWeapon = currentWeapon == type ? currentWeapon : type; //change current weapon if necessary
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The type element in the Weapon object represent if it is a primary(rifle) or a secondary(pistol) weapon.
What should I do beside creating another object to store the object the pointer is headed to?

Comment: You could simply store all weapons in a single vector containing all weapon data regardless of whether it's on the ground,in an inventory or somewhere else.Simply use vectors of pointers or `std::reference_wrapper`s to store lists of items on the ground,in an inventory or somewhere else.Note that you need to make sure the vector containing the actual data never needs to reallocate it's backing storage and never moves the items around for the addresses in the vector to remain stable.The simplest approach by far would be to simply store shared pointers to the items,but beware memory fragmentatio

Comment: Do you know that a pointer doesn't store an object? It just points to an object that is stored somewhere else.

Comment: I wrote my address "123 Main St" on a napkin and gave it to the real estate agent to sell. Then since he had the address, I didn't need the house any more so I signed the demolition order. But then when the real estate agent came to see my house he said it was a pile of rubble. I told him that was nonsense - I demolished the house *after* I gave him the address.

Comment: You'll find similar problems when writing pointers to storage. If you write the pointer, odds are by the time the storage is read back in and the pointer's recovered, the object it pointed at will be gone. You almost always need to write the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got some confusion with memory and what should be a pointer. I'm looking specifically at how you store your weapons here:

```
std::vector<Weapon> droppedWeapons = {}; //dropped pickable weapons on the ground
std::vector<Weapon*> weapons = {nullptr, nullptr}; //slots for the primary and secondary weapon
```

When you pickup a weapon you are currently assigning the pointer to the memory location of the Weapon object in your vector, but then immediately removing that weapon! That's why you observed that it appears you equipped the wrong weapon. The weapon you picked up has gone, the `std::vector` has been resized and the next one has shunted down to fill it's place (`std::vector`s are required to be hold their elements in contiguous memory). This operation could also leave a dangling pointer e.g. if the weapon you tried to pick up was the last in the `droppedWeapons` vector your `weapons` pointer would end up pointing past the end of the vector.

Without changing too much of the rest of your code, you could change `droppedWeapons` to a vector of `Weapon*` (weapon pointers), rather than `Weapon`. Then when you want to pickup the weapon, assign the pointer to your picked up weapons list like so:

```
weapons[type] = droppedWeapons.at(i); // pass weapon pointer
```

Followed by removing the element from `droppedWeapons` as you are already.

Now you are working with pointers you will have to fill `droppedWeapons` by allocating them with `new`, and cleanup all your `Weapon*` at some point with `delete`.

Before making this change, it may also be a good idea to learn more about stack vs heap memory allocation in c++ if you aren't familiar with it already :)